# Creating buttons with a JavaScript class

Tags: javascript, class, object, dom

So I decided to make a little website for storing my recipes, like a digital recipe book. That way, I can access and edit them from anywhere by changing a few lines in the Javascript(no messing with files). Each recipe appears when you click its button and disappears when you click its hide button.

There are two versions. There is an old version, where the recipes are written in. There's prewritten HTML for their buttons, and they're in object literal in the javascript. It is on the gh-pages branch of the github repository, and used and the github page. It worked, so I tried to make the more dynamic second version.
The second version is on the recipes-object-oriented branch of the github repository. It has a class creator so I can add recipes just by calling it. It establishes the properties, gives each recipe its own method for the update/hide functions, and also attempts to make the HTML for them and their buttons using the DOM. It doesn't work.

I don't know for certain what code is causing the second version to not work, but I suspect it is with the buttons. I have one recipe declared, but its buttons aren't appearing. I haven't seen anyone make HTML with a class before, so this may not be the right way to do it.
Any thoughts on the problem with it, or other parts of the code? I'm not very experienced with javaScript (just a middle school student), so apologies if I have no clue what I'm doing.

GitHub repository: https://github.com/skwawk/recipes
jsfiddle for second version: https://jsfiddle.net/psz3do70/1/ 

Following is the code for the second version's class function.

```
function Recipe(id, name, ingredients, steps,) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.title = "<h2>" + name + "</h2>";
    this.ingredients = ingredients;
    this.steps = steps;

    //the part that I'm worried about
    var btn = document.createElement("input");
    btn.type = "button";
    btn.name = this.id;
    btn.value = this.name;
    btn.onclick = this.update;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.id = this.id;
    document.body.appendChild(div);

    this.printRecipe = function () {
            console.log(this.name);
            console.log();
            console.log(this.ingredients);
            console.log();
            console.log(this.steps);
    };
    this.update = function () {
        recipeDiv = document.getElementById(name);
        recipeDiv.innerHTML = this.title + this.ingredients + "<br /><br />" + this.steps;
    };
    this.hide = function() {
        recipeDiv = document.getElementById(name);
        recipeDiv.innerHTML = "";
    };

};
```

There's practically no HTML for the second version, just the recipes heading.
Thanks for looking at this, and thanks in advance for any answers!

Edit: Thanks for feedback! I have fixed a few errors you found (and which I should have caught), but it's still not working. At least we're closer to finding out when it does!

Comment: At first rapid sight, on the `btn.onclick` you're assigning the function's result, not a function reference. You've to remove the parenthesis. Also the `function.getElementById` is wrong, it should be called on `document`.

Comment: Didn't see it at first. Look at your `getElementByid` methods. You pass the `name` parameter when you should pass the `this.name` property. BTW is the `this.name` or `this.id` property the one you want to pass to `getElementById` method?